# How to rebind variable assignments

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am currently attempting to build my own JS framework as a way to learn.  I have created a method for making an new model like so:

```
var myModel = new $n.model.make({
    data: {
        id: _contentID,
        name: $('#frm_content_name').val()
    },
    route: '/my/path',
    callback: function(){}
});
```

The make() function is simple:

```
$n.model.make = function(obj){

    var self = this;

    self.data = obj.data;
    self.route = obj.route;
    self.callback = obj.callback;

}
```

As you can see, the name parameter is assigned to a form input field's value.  If I change this input field value on the UI, the name parameter is still assigned to the original value of the input field so if I try to save the data to the DB, nothing has changed.

Once I have established my model, what is a good way to "rebind" the data parameters to their assigned form fields to get the latest information?

Comment: Why don't you set your object property to reference the field itself and then retrieve its value when needed?

Comment: I may potentially have 20 or more form fields that are referenced in the model.  It was easier when I had the data definitions within a generic saveData() function and it would bind right before it saved.  Seems to me that having a dedicated model just complicates things, unless I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for - two-way data binding.  Here is the tutorial I used to solve my issue: http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment you could do this:

```
data: {
    id: _contentID,
    name: function() {
        return $('#frm_content_name').val();
    }
},
```

Calling `data.name()` would always fetch the latest information. Another way is this:

```
data {
    id: _contentID,
    name: $('#frm_content_name')
},
```

Now you would need to call `data.name.val()`; personally I don't really like this because of the missing encapsulation.